# AWS instance storage replication to EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to synchronously replicate data on an instances ephemeral disks to EBS volumes, using block device mapping or similar ?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronously?  The EBS would likely have a hard time keeping up, or an impossible time in an i2/d2 scenario with heavy I/O and throughput, even with EBS Optimization.

A quick search of EBS Optimization will show throughputs/IOPS to EBS by instance type, and you'll see that an i2 to ephemeral would crush most of those numbers.  You would be better off replicating the i2 instance and ephemerals to another i2 instance and ephemeral stack here.

Comment: How about asynchronously using GlusterFS or similar?